# Installing Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 X64

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2005 Professional on Windows 7 X64 and it fails quickly while installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 64bit Prerequisites (x64).  The install error logs includes the following:

> [08/25/09,14:46:14] Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] Component Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 64bit Prerequisites (x64) returned an unexpected value.
>
> [08/25/09,14:46:17] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InstallManagerHelper() with HRESULT -2147023293.
>
> [08/25/09,14:46:17] setup.exe: [2] Component error string not specified in ISetupManager::AddToActionResultCollection()

Windows 7 provides this additional information:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:                 InPageError
Error Status Code:                  c000000d
Faulting Media Type:                00000000
OS Version:                         6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:                          1033
Additional Information 1:           0a9e
Additional Information 2:           0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:           0a9e
Additional Information 4:           0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Efforts to search for this problem on the Internet have not produced anything useful so far so I thought I would ask here.  Is it just me or have others experienced this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some help from a managed MSDN forum and some luck I got this installed.  Some of the steps I took made no sense but I thought I should document this for others.

I extracted the Prerequisites installer by running \wcu\64bitPrereq\vs_bsln.exe using the /C switch then ran the installer with logging using this command from an Administrator Command Prompt:

```
msiexec /package vs_bsln.msi /log <filename>
```

This gave me a different error message:

```
MSI (s) (C4:D4) [09:14:54:489]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 64bit
Prerequisites (x64) - ENU -- Error 1945.You do not have sufficient privileges
to complete the re-advertisement of this product. Re-advertisement requires
initiation by a local system account calling the MsiAdvertiseScript API, such
as through Group Policy Software Deployment.
```

The rest does not really make sense to me but I repeated that above command logged in as a domain Administrator rather than a local Administrator and the Prerequisites installed!

So I tried installing Visual Studio again and it did not attempt to install the prerequisites but failed with the same message on the next component (Document Explorer, as I recall).  I tried launching \vs\setup.exe as Administrator and it worked.

UPDATE 10/21/09:  This problem may have been related to running the install from a shared DVD drive on another computer.  If you encounter a problem like this and you are running the install over a network, trying copying the install locally.

Answer (score 5):

When trying to install Visual Studio 2005 Standard on a Win7-x64 machine I kept running into a problem where it would display an error that included the following bits of information then rollback the install (I don't have the complete error because the messagebox wouldn't let me copy the text):

```
Error 1935 "microsoft.vc80.atl" HRESULT 0x80070bc9
```

Various suggestions found on the Internet seemed to have no effect (I do not have Domain Admin access to the machine and cannot get it) until I tried the following:

- open Control Panel's "Programs and Features" applet
- select "Turn Windows features on or off"
- make sure all the items related to "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" were turned on.  Specifically, the Windows Communication Foundation HTTP and non-HTTP Activation items were off and I turned them on.  I have no idea what these things are for beyond what might be suggested in the names.

After I did this, the VS2005 installation worked, but it did complain several times about incompatibilities.  However, I was able to tell those dialogs to just keep running the program and everything seemed to work fine.

Now I'm off to install VS 2005 SP1 and the SP1 Vista and Win7 updates.

Answer (score 2):

Hay I have Just Install Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7

First i was Trying to Install Direct From DVD Image. i give Below Error

Problem Event Name:                 InPageError

Then i Copy DVD on my Drive and Run setup in Administrative mode its Start installing..

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Variation on this theme:  I had the same problem; I was getting errors writing to the C:\windows\winsxs directory; I took ownership of that directory, and all its subdirectories (right click on the folder, properties, security, advanced, owner tab, edit, changed owner to myself, checked the box at lower left (replace subdirectories etc).  That enabled me to re-run the VS 2005 installer and it ran.  I ignored the compatibility errors and selected "Run Program".